# Why is my code not iterating?

Tags: c#, linq, delayed-execution

Why is my code not working as expected? The others (departmentName, employeeName and statusDescription) are working (shown below)

```
int countRow = 1;
//Query for account status
var query = from emp in db.EmployeeDetails
            join stat in db.Status on emp.statusId equals stat.statusId
            join dep in db.Department on emp.departmentId equals dep.departmentId
            where emp.employeeName == name
            select new { emp, stat, dep };  
foreach (var q in query)
{

    Console.WriteLine("{0,-3} | {1,-10} | {2,10}\t\t | {3,10}",
       countRow,
       q.dep.departmentName,
       q.emp.employeeName,
       q.stat.statusDescription);                
    Console.WriteLine("-----------");                
    countRow++;// <---------not adding: output keeps printing 1
}
```

It's working but my `countRow` is constantly having a value of 1

Right now, my output looks like this:

```
No.      Dep             Name      Status
1        Finance         John      Present
1        Education       Mary      Present
1        Recreational    Tom       Absent
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
No.      Dep             Name      Status
1        Finance         John      Present
2        Education       Mary      Present
3        Recreational    Tom       Absent
```

UPDATE:
It appears my "query" (in foreach var q in query) has a count value of 1. I suppose this is the cause of my issue. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: "not iterating" ? What's not happening? Does your query return results?

Comment: Is the code you posted the working code or the broken code?

Comment: It's working but my countRow is constantly having a value of 1

Comment: Is there any element in query variable?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the "foreach (var q in query)" line, highlight "q", press SHIFT+F9. Check that the results are what you expect.

Comment: Try countRow += 1; see if it does the same, or ++countRow;

Comment: print query.count() to see how many elements are actually are in the query

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The `countRow++` is fine, no need for `countRow += 1`

Comment: the code is working for me, have you got a conditional breakpoint that is doing something like countRow=1 , which will assign 1 to the value (I have done this in my younger days )

Comment: @Micky I'm aware it's probably not the problem, however I have seen that be a problem and only print out the countRow val and not countRow+1 before

Comment: Are you sure that this query isn't executed 3 times? It looks that you are filtering by employee name, so by given output it had to be executed separately. Try move rowCount higher in code.

Comment: I have tested your `Console.WriteLine` in a for-loop with a counter that i increase with `countRow++` as you did, it works.

Comment: It appears my "query" has a count value of 1. I've tried both countRow++ and countRow += 1 and they don't seem to be helping. Also, my query is executed once only, not twice. @Steve What do you mean? I don't quite understand. Thanks everyone for the helpful inputs :)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code, if you but a breakpoint on the `countRow++` you should see it going up. If you have not added any conditional breakpoint then my watch theory will not be valid. Step over your code and keep an eye on `countRow`

Comment: As Pawel stated, the code you posted is either not the code being run or is being run three times with different parameters. The query contains `where emp.employeeName == name` so will only return results for a single name. Yet the output contains John, Mary, and Tom. So to reiterate what others have said your loop is almost certainly OK. Step through using a debugger to find out what is going on. It's probably an issue with code not in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're posting the results of multiple queries.

Your original query looks for a specific name (`emp.employeeName == name`) which yields, probably, a single result. The results you posted have multiple names in them, which means you're running this query more than once (maybe in an enclosing loop?). Each query initializes `countRow` to 1, so you get the same number every time.
If you had multiple employees with the same name, you'd see numbers other than 1. As the comments suggest, try to find the enclosing loop and move the `countRow = 1` initializer there.